# Is it possible to execute script-containing string in script scope?

Tags: powershell

Keeping in mind the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), here are my X and Y problems.

#### X Problem

There are PowerShell scripts, the contents of which I have obfuscated. I am still able to run the script, however.

How this is working is that the scripts are stored inside an executable. PowerShell can execute the executable, asking for a particular script by passing in that script's name as a CLI parameter. The executable's process will then forward the PowerShell script's content through stdout. PowerShell stores the stdout in a string variable, then calls [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1), passing in the string, running the obfuscated script.

The problem is that [$PSScriptRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#other-script-features), when it occurs in the obfuscated scripts, is evaluated as `$null`.

#### Y Problem

When a PowerShell script, `script.ps1` executes a PowerShell script as a string `$scriptString`, how to get `$PSScriptRoot` to evaluate as if it were evaluated in `script.ps1`.

**Test 1**

```
# script.ps1

$PSScriptRoot

# Output: Path to directory containing `script.ps1`.
```

This demonstrates that `$PSScriptRoot` is non-`$null` in at least one case.

**Test 2**

```
# script.ps1

Invoke-Expression '$PSScriptRoot'

# Output: Nothing
```

Demonstrates that the way that I am currently executing the string does not work.

**Test 3**

```
# script.ps1

. { $PSScriptRoot }

# Output: Path to directory containing `script.ps1`.
```

Creating a script block using the `{ ... }` syntax does work. This requires the actual commands, however. What I have is a string containing the commands. Putting that string between the curly braces would cause commands to be output rather than run.

**Test 4**

```
# script.ps1

. [ScriptBlock]::Create('$PSScriptRoot')

# Output: Nothing
```

The other way to create a script block is with the C# `[ScriptBlock]::Create(...)` method. This actually allows creating a script block from a string. Unfortunately, it does not work.

**Test 5**

```
# script.ps1

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $PSScriptRoot }

# Output: Path to directory containing `script.ps1`.
```

Same as test 3, except calling `Invoke-Command` on the script block rather than dot-sourcing the script block.

**Test 6**

```
# script.ps1

$scriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create('$PSScriptRoot')
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

# Output: Nothing.
```

Same as test 3, except calling `Invoke-Command` on the script block rather than dot-sourcing the script block.

#### Current belief about the problem.

- The only way that I know of to execute a string-script as a string
  directly is the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet, which does not work.
  Maybe there is another way to execute a string directly which might
  work, but I do not know about.
- The other way to execute the string-script is to convert the string into a script block, then execute the script block. There seem to be
  two ways of creating a script block, one which works and one which
  does not work.

  - Creating a script block using the `{ ... }` syntax seems to work, but it does not appear to work with strings.
  - Creating a script block using the `[ScriptBlock]::Create(...)` method does not work, but works with strings.

#### Questions:

- Is there a way to execute a string directly which will work without calling `Invoke-Expression`?
- Is there a way to create a script block from a string using the `{ ... }` syntax?
- What is the reason/mechanism behind the test scenarios working/not working?
- Most importantly, how can we execute a string script and get `$PSScriptRoot` to evaluate to the proper, non-`$null` value?

Comment: Try using double quotes

Comment: To construct the string or for some other reason?  The string is constructed properly, so that is not the issue.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, this appears to be a problem with scope.

`$PSScriptRoot` is available in the script scope.  A script block created with `{ ... }` has access to the `$PSScriptRoot` script-scope variable, whereas a script block created with `[ScriptBlock]::Create(...)`.  Does not have access to the `$PSScriptRoot` script-scope variable.

`{ ... }` solves the scope problem except that only commands can be entered in the `{ ... }` syntax.  There does not appear to be a way to get the commands in a string to be the commands of a script block without using the `[ScriptBlock]::Create()` method.

Comment: `iex 'Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName'`

Comment: and then there is that - @SantiagoSquarzon to the rescue :)

Comment: @Daniel, yes, I want `$PSScriptRoot` to be evaluated when the script block is evaluated, not when the script block is created, just like what is done in the test cases.

The string containing a script contains many commands with `$PSScriptRoot` being evaluated in some of the commands.  I would like `$PSScriptRoot` to be evaluated correctly like it is in `. { $PSScriptRoot }`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, that is rather ingenious. If I could modify the obfuscated scripts, that would work. Unfortunately, the original problem still stands.

I am trying to execute the script contained in a string `$stringScript` while still having `$PSScriptRoot` evaluate correctly.  Is this impossible in PowerShell?

Comment: $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot seems to work.  $PSScriptRoot by itself does not seem to get auto-populated in scriptblocks

Comment: @Daniel, `. { $PSScriptRoot }` is a script block and it evaluates `$PSScriptRoot` as a non-`$null` value.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, `$MyInvokation.InvokationName` does not appear to be a solution. There is a difference. Calling a script as `PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> . .\script.ps1` gives an
InvokationName of `.` and a PSScriptRoot of `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop`.

Comment: Did you have a good look at all the properties `$MyInvocation` has to offer? There is one that will work for what you need. In addition `Invocation` is spelled with C not K :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, The `$PSScriptRoot` property, I see.  That might be a good workaround should it come to that.

Comment: I was actually referring to `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source`, this would give you the full path of the script being executed and it gets resolved even when you dot source the script. You could then `Split-Path` to get the script folder. All of these using `iex`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, the reason that these proposed solutions don't work is that they require modifying the scripts. There should be a way to create a script block from arbitrary commands and have it execute in the context of the current script. Mathias's answer provides that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make PowerShell treat a script stored in a string *as if it had been read off disk* - that is, `$PSScriptRoot` and `$PSCommandPath` will resolve correctly - by manually parsing it:

```
# Prepare script + path
$script = 'Write-Host "Script root:  $PSScriptRoot`nCommand path: $PSCommandPath"'
$fileName = "C:\my\path\to\script.ps1"

# Make the parser generate an AST from the input script + path
$AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($script, $fileName, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)

# Get an executable scriptblock from AST
$block = $AST.GetScriptBlock()

# Now invoke it
& $block
```

At which point you'll find the `$PS*` variables have been resolved correctly:

```
Script root:  C:\my\path\to
Command path: C:\my\path\to\script.ps1
```