# Powershell inside a CMD file (hybrid) - Looking for pointers on how to handle file contents (MemoryStream/TempFile/TxtReplace?)

Tags: powershell, cmd

This is a hybrid CMD\Powershell script. Inside, the CMD portion at the top of the script requests elevation from UAC if it is enabled, or automatically self elevates if not(if possible), and there is a one-liner Powershell command containing GC and text .Replace that parses the CMD file like any text file and allows Powershell to be run from inside.

It is a very basic example, for simple scripts.

Before spending too much time with the .Replace method I'm using, I was wondering if there is a more direct way to approach grabbing the PS code and running it, right now if your code can be used as a one liner without edits this will convert and run it. I was thinking maybe a conversion to base64 then running it as an encoded command to be able to handle more complex scripts? I'm unsure which direction to go, any suggestions would be appreciated.

This PS code is an example that uses BITS to download Adobe Reader DC to the same folder as the CMD file.

**Ninja.cmd** Updated w/help from @mklement0 (thank you!)

```
<# ::
@ECHO OFF
>nul 2>&1 reg add hkcu\software\classes\.PSninja\shell\runas\command /f /ve /d "cmd /x /d /r set \"f0=%%2\"& call \"%%2\" %%3"& set _= %*
>nul 2>&1 fltmc|| if "%f0%" neq "%~f0" (cd.>"%temp%\runas.PSninja" & start "%~n0" /high "%temp%\runas.PSninja" "%~f0" "%_:"=""%" & exit /b)
>nul 2>&1 reg delete hkcu\software\classes\.PSninja\ /f & >nul 2>&1 del %temp%\runas.PSninja /f /q
POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -c "POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -en ([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((GC '%~f0' -raw) -Replace('###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###','$PSScriptRoot=$pwd;$PSCommandPath=''%~f0'';Set-Location ''%~dp0'''))))"
GOTO :EOF
#>
###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###
$Url='http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/2000920063/AcroRdrDC2000920063_en_US.exe'
function Size-To-Human-Readable([uint64]$size){
    $suffix = "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"
    $i = 0
    while ($size -gt 1kb) {
        $size = $size / 1kb
        $i++
    }
"{0:N1} {1}" -f $size, $suffix[$i]
}
$pattern='.*\/(.*\.exe).*'
$File=[regex]::Match($Url, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$str_size=(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $Url -Method Head).Headers.'Content-Length'
$tmp_size=[uint64]::Parse($str_size)
$Size=Size-To-Human-Readable $tmp_size
Write-Host "Downloading '$File' ($Size)..."
Start-BitsTransfer -Priority Foreground -Source $Url -Destination $File
```

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063524/45375) helps. You should be able to put the self-elevating part in the PowerShell section of the code.

Comment: @mklement0 I used info from your post and added encoding and now it seems to run everything *Updated in OP. (I'm not worried about args at this time but i see the work you've done with that and I'm sure I'll revisit. You are awesome thanks again!!)

Comment: This topic is of interest me, I developed my own BATCH bootstrap for PowerShell, but still new enough to PowerShell that I don't know how my method compares to your Base64 version. `SET CLA=%*`, `IF DEFINED CLA SET CLA=%CLA:'=''%`, `IF DEFINED CLA SET CLA=%CLA:"='%`, `SET f0=%~f0`, `SET "ASSEMBLY1=Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;"`, `START "Title" /MIN PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "%ASSEMBLY1%$Input | . ([System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput((get-content -raw $Env:f0), $Env:f0, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)).GetScriptBlock() %CLA%"`

Comment: The `ParseInput` trick is derived from [Mathias R. Jessen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517934/4190564)

Comment: @Darin Im not sure if I can apply that to the encoded command route I'm using.

Comment: @Darin I updated the OP i got it to work by manually adding the vars into the CMD without using system management automation ;) In my case the workingdir is allways the dir the script is run from which is 50% of the problem ($pwd), the rest can be solved via cmd

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp, I'm wondering about the need for Base64.  Is that because you are calling PowerShell from within an already running PowerShell?  About a year ago I was was doing experiments running PowerShell 7.x from PowerShell 5.1 and discovered the two were passing very complex objects such as hash tables to each other just fine.  Further investigation proved the calling PowerShell was encoding (I think it was base64) its objects and passing that encoded text to the PowerShell being called.

Comment: There is [stackoverflow] [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) which I think is more appropriate for conducting your conversation with @Darin rather than via comments.